# How do I send the 'this' pointer to a function not by using 'instance.function()'?

Tags: c++, oop

Can I send an instance to a function not by using the `.` operator?

For example:

```cpp
// header file
class A 
{
public:
    void foo() {std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;}
};
```

```cpp
// main file
A instance = new A;
instance.foo();
// instead do something like this
A::foo(instance);
```

Can I do something like that?

Comment: You'd need to change the function to be `static` and accept a `A*` as argument. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Unless that isn't supposed to be a `A*` in your "main file" - it's unclear because you have non-compiling code in that snippet

Comment: my question is, can I send the instance to its method without using the . operator

Comment: Well, you *could* write `(instance.*&A::foo)()` and that would be operator `.*` rather than `.`, or if you *really* hate periods `std::invoke(&A::foo, instance)`. But that's all pretty silly, so what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the language more at the implementation level. ```std::invoke(&A::foo, instance)``` was what I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: @reem_mikulsky `A instance = new A; instance.foo();` doesn't compile. You would need to use either `A instance; instance.foo();` or `A *instance = new A; instance->foo(); delete instance;` instead.

Comment: @reem_mikulsky `std::invoke` just uses `.` internally, it's not magical. You could also do `(&instance)->foo();`.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you do the normal thing aka `instance->foo()`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indirectly via [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  void foo() {
    std::cerr << "hi\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  std::invoke(&A::foo,a);
}
```

But `std::invoke`'s implementation will internally probably just apply the `.*` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You're more than welcome to use the [pointer to member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/pointer-to-member-operators-dot-star-and-star?view=msvc-170) syntax.

```
A instance;
auto fn = &A::foo;
(instance.*fn)();
```

`.*` is a different operator than `.`. Whether this is more readable is left as an exercise to the reader (hint: it's not)